# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was String at line 1 column 5

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am not able to upload an image to my server from android application. My json seems right.
Here is my code.

```
private boolean uploadprofilePic(String user_id)
    {
        final Boolean[] imageresponse = new Boolean[1];
        if(imageadded) { //get the image
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) profileImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

            //set data
            //String user_id =sharedpreferences.getString("user_id","");
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imageInByte);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "image_" + user_id + ".jpg", requestFile);
            //assert user_id != null;
            RequestBody userId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), user_id);

            //call the api
            loginApiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(LoginApiInterface.class);

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialogPopup.showProgressDialog(this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.loading), "");
            Call<ProfilePicUploadResponse> call = loginApiInterface.uploadprofilePic(body, userId);

            imageresponse[0] = false;
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfilePicUploadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ProfilePicUploadResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ProfilePicUploadResponse> response) {
                    //Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Here i m", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //AlertPopup.alertDialogShow(EditProfileActivity.this, response.message(), "");
                    ProfilePicUploadResponse profilePicUploadResponse = response.body();
                    if (profilePicUploadResponse.getError() != null){
                        imageresponse[0] = true;
                        assert response.body() != null;
                        setResult(1);
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Here i m", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "it is successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //AlertPopup.alertDialogShow(EditProfileActivity.this, response.body().getMessage().toString(), "");
                    } else {
                        //Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Not success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageresponse[0] = false;
                        AlertPopup.alertDialogShow(EditProfileActivity.this, "Some error occurred", "");
                    /*setResult(1);
                    finish();*/
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ProfilePicUploadResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) { progressDialog.dismiss();
                    imageresponse[0] = false;
                    AlertPopup.alertDialogShow(EditProfileActivity.this, t.getMessage(), "");
                /*setResult(1);
                finish();*/
                }
            });
            return imageresponse[0];
        }
        else {
            setResult(1);
            finish();
            return imageresponse[0];
        }

    }
```

I have Pojo class named ProfilePicUploadResponse.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ProfilePicUploadResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Boolean error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public ProfilePicUploadResponse withError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
        return this;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ProfilePicUploadResponse withMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I have passed gson as well to retrofit builder

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static Retrofit retrofit=null;
    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit==null)
        {
            //scalar is for text and gson for json obect and arrays
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(base_url)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return  retrofit;
    }
}
```

Every time I upload a new image it goes into OnFailure(). The call is asynchronous as it is calling .enqueue method.

Here is the my json response.

```
{“file_name”:“CONSOLATION_Instagram.jpg”,“user_id”:“3461",“task_id”:“6875",“message”:“Your Art is uploaded successfully!“,”error”:false,“file_path”:“https:\/\/yourmasterpieces.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/media\/artworks\/v3\/image_3461_6875.jpg”}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
{“file_name”:“CONSOLATION_Instagram.jpg”,“user_id”:“3461",“task_id”:“6875",“message”:“Your Art is uploaded successfully!“,”error”:false,“file_path”:“https:\/\/yourmasterpieces.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/media\/artworks\/v3\/image_3461_6875.jpg”}
```

line 1 column 5 in your json response is `”error”:false`.

You are trying to use boxed data type (i.e. Boolean) instead of using primitive data type (boolean) which is not supported during parsing.

So in your response class, use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`.

```java
public class ProfilePicUploadResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private boolean error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    ....
```

Comment: Hi @Sagar I have changed the data type to boolean but still, it is going into OnFailure.  But when I change MultipartBody.Part variable to MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.create(requestFile);  Then It goes into OnResponse instead of OnFailure but it does not update image.

Comment: For image upload using retrofit I found a nice article. Please take a refrence from it.
https://androidclarified.com/android-image-upload-example/